# Disconnect, then reconnect pin

Tags: directx, directshow.net, slimdx

I'm using DirectShow.net and SlimDX to put a video texture on a quad. I've got a problem on device lost. I'm not able to reset my device. After hours of googling, I've find a forum topic where the solution was to disconnect the vmr9 pin, reset the device and reconnect the pin.

I know how to disconnect :

```
IPin pin;
vmr9.FindPin("VMR Input0", out pin);
pin.Disconnect();
```

and with this, reset is OK, but how can I connect again ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found this :

```
IPin pin;
IPin receivePin;
vmr9.FindPin("VMR Input0", out pin);
pin.ConnectedTo(out receivePin);
pin.Disconnect();
receivePin.Disconnect();
```

To reconnect :

```
pin.Connect(receivePin, null);
```

Seems to work.